# Can i update ubuntu 13.10 from iso file in ubuntu itself?

Tags: 13.04

I downloaded ubuntu 13.10 file from internet,but ive to update ubuntu 13.04 without net connection can it be done using the iso file?

Comment: If you want to update Ubuntu, all you have to do is type `do-release-upgrade` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! You can do this. 
Follow these steps

- Create a LiveCD or Live USB as you would normally do.
- Start the installation from the media created.
- At the installation type screen in the installer, select "Upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04"

This will upgrade Ubuntu to 13.10 preserving programs and your files. Backup is still recommended.